What does Simone mean by "an animal born in a butcher's shop" when referring to her "ponce" in Mona Lisa?
What is the meaning of Simone's phrase to refer to her "ponce":

An animal born in a butcher's shop

in HandMade Film's Mona Lisa (1986)?
Here's the script:

Simone:  Anderson?
George:  Yeah.
Simone:  Anderson is a ponce, a pimp.
George:  Your ponce?
Simone:  An animal born in a butcher's shop.
George:  But have you got a ponce now?
Simone:  No, got you.
George:  Did he knock you about?
Simone:  He used to adjust my face, yes.


This is an example of both literal and figurative speech being used in a single sentence, which is why it might be difficult to parse.


"An animal".


Animal: (noun) A person displaying vulgar manners, attitudes, etc; a
despicable human being; a brute
The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English

Her former pimp (her 'ponce') certainly has vulgar manners. We learn that he periodically beat her.

A butcher's shop


Butcher Shop: (noun) a store where animals are killed, cut up, dressed and prepared for sale.

The area of London in which the film is set (King's Cross) was known in the 1980s for being significantly deprived and home to substantial gangland activity including killings and enforced prostitution. This is the 'butcher's shop', where lives are routinely taken apart for their value.

Her former pimp is therefore 'a vulgar person, who has grown up in a part of the world where people are routinely killed'.
